# UDP Packet Creation With Scapy

Tags: python-3.x, networking, udp, ip, scapy

I am having trouble sending custom UDP packets with Scapy on Python3 with a MacBook. 
 want to send a UDP packet with a custom Source IP of `192.168.1.11` to my current machine with the IP of, `192.168.1.17` that is hosting a `UDP` Server on port `6789`. I want to send a message saying "Hi" using Scapy so I wrote the following code,

```
from scapy.all import *
from random import randrange
sendp(IP(src="192.168.11",dst="192.168.1.17")/UDP(sport=randrange(80,65535),dport=6789)/"Hi",iface="en0",count=10)
```

Then I have a server waiting to respond once data is received and print the message received to the screen. But when executing this code with elevated privileges, scapy says 
`the packets were sent but the server didn't receive the response.`

So I went to `en0` the wireless interface on my Mac to debug. This is what I found:

Wireshark says

```
the source is Applicon_11:f8:61, the destination is 45:00:00:1e:00:01, the protocol is 0xc0a8(Unknown) and the data is 16 bytes of Hex: 0000   45 00 00 1e 00 01 00 00 40 11 f8 61 c0 a8 00 0b ASCII Dump:  E.......@.øaÀ¨..
0010   c0 a8 01 11 67 18 1a 85 00 0a b3 66 48 69         À¨..g.....³fHi
```

I have no idea what any of that means or what I am doing wrong here can anyone help to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendp` is for sending at layer 2
`send` is for sending at layer 3

In your case, you should either use

- at layer 2: `sendp(Ether()/IP(..)....)`. (Replace `Ether` by `Loopback` if needed)
- at layer 3: `send(IP(...))`

Comment: I used the send method like you said and the packets seem to go through when I use the command `send(IP(src='192.168.1.11',dst='192.168.1.17')/UDP(dport=6789),iface='en0',loop=1)` but not without an error .WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast.
 When I add the payload to say "Hi", `send(IP(src='192.168.1.11',dst='192.168.1.17')/UDP(dport=6789)/"Hi",iface='en0',loop=1)` Wireshark says the packet is malformed, it doesn't go through and says the protocol is DNS and no longer UDP.

Comment: Update, the later sometimes works but it isn't predictable and when I try to send larger message it fails entirely.